# User input for a curl request

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

It seems I can't use a variable for as a post argument for curl. I can't understand why it's not working. I tried to print the variable, and the variable is exactly like I want it to be... If I put directly as an argument: "useremail=testuser&password=lol123&action=login&remember=remember"; it works fine, but I want to use a user input variable...

```
int main(void){
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
std::string readBuffer;

std::string testinput;

std::cin >> testinput;

std::string data = "useremail=" + testinput + "&password=lol123&action=login&remember=remember";

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {



    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://manager.domain.pro/api.php");
    /* Now specify the POST data */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

}
return 0;}
```

Comment: Could there be a newline as the last character of the test input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ...);
```

doesn't take a `std::string` as third parameter but a pointer to `char` so you should pass it `data.c_str()` and hope that `curl_easy_setup()` won't try to modifie the data since `std::string::c_str()` returns a `char const *`.

Comment: Changing the data variable in the argument to data.c_str() actually fixed my problem! I'm a bit new to c++ & libcurl, thanks !

Comment: @Jobine23 [Read the documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html)